# MimeKit HtmlBody thread

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

I am parsing an email using MimeKit on C#. The HTMLBody contains the entire thread of email replies. Is there are way to extract just the latest HTMLBody of the email in MimeKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MimeKit doesn't provide any way to do this because it's not specified by any MIME specifications.

You'll have to come up with your own solution to do this because every mail client generates different HTML.